# How to get updated shared preferences value within a fragment?

Tags: android, preferences, shared

I have a fragment that i use to get some info from the database and display them to their respective textviews, but there is a problem because my fragment doesn't get the updated values, it still displays the previous values until i restart the app. i tried to use onchangedlistener but without success, does anyone have any idea how could i refresh and update shared preferences without closing the respective fragment.

here is a bit of code where the issue happens:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_showinfo, null);

    // i send my current user's id to the database, to get his info.
    // the problems happens here because the context is loaded from getActivity() and is not closed so i can get the new values.

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    getid = prefs.getString("currentid", null);

    //AsyncTask class used to connect with db.
    //on post execute it stores the info received from the db into the shared preferences.

    Connection_db connection = new Connection_db(
            getActivity());
    connection.execute(connection_request, getid);

    // i tried to reinitialize the shared prefs in order to get the new values ( i tried to use the SP from above but still won't work).
    SharedPreferences prefs_update = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    info_one = prefs_update.getString("info_one", "something");
    textView.setText(info_one);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the easiest to troubleshoot without the logcat printout, but I would assume that the problem is coming from this line here:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences
```

I haven't worked with android in about a month, but if I'm not mistaken it should be:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreference
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i can't use getApplicationContext inside a fragment. i also have an application class from which i can get a static context, but still i can't get it to work,

Comment: i still can't get the new values, it still shows the previous everytime i restart my app

Comment: So I'm confused on what you're trying to do then, you're trying to pull data from a server and then save it to shared preferences, or you're using shared preferences to pull data from a server?

Comment: I try to be clear, here's the lifecycle of what i do: i have the user id in shared preferences after the login , in this fragment i retrieve that id and i send that id to the server, and i get the infos of that id (first name , last name etc...) then i store them into the shared preferences. so before the connection to the server i initialize a shared preferences to get the id, now after the connection i need to get the updated values that the connection class puts inside shared preferences. i hope you understand what i mean, sorry for my english if it isn't clear

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. Your english is perfectly fine! So at the very beginning you want to try to retrieve those values in shared preferences, in the second parameter leave an empty string for when it returns null. Then in `postExecute` write the data to `sharedPreferences` and at the very end run a `postDelayed` that would simply reload the new shared preferences data

Comment: I tried what you said, now , but it won't work. i can't find a solution for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118345/discussion-between-user154248-and-homombi).

Answer (score 0):

I am using PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) to get and update prefernce values .
 you can also  make static method in some class as below 
and  access it by passing context ( of service, activity etc) directly.

```
public static void  setSSIDOption(Context c , Boolean b) {

   SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(IS_SSID_EXCLUDED, b);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public static  Boolean getSSIDOption(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        return settings.getBoolean(IS_EXCLUDED, false);
    }
```